# Deserialize json to a customize object with json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize json-formatted response below.

```
{
  "context": "xxxxxx"
  "value": [
      {
        "Id": "123"
        "Time": "2022-12-01"
      }
      {
        "Id": "123"
        "Time": "2022-12-01"
      }
      ....
  ]
}
```

According to this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm, this code should work.

```
 public class WorkingSetContent
    {
        /// <summary>Collection ID</summary>
        [JsonProperty("context")]
        public string Context { get; set; }

        /// <summary>UserRelationship</summary>
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public IList<ItemClass> Items { get; set; }
   }
```

But I'm getting a build error : "Change 'Items' to be read-only by removing the property setter."

I changed the setter to private to avoid this build error, then I was able to run it, but it causes a runtime error as null value is passed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your json

```
 {
  "context": "xxxxxx",
  "value": [
      {
        "Id": "123",
        "Time": "2022-12-01"
      },
      {
        "Id": "123",
        "Time": "2022-12-01"
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: JSON.NET has no difficulty figuring out how to populate an `IList` property. OP is just running up against a code analysis rule that probably shouldn't apply to DTO classes like this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2227) is the code analysis rule you're running up against.

One option is to initialize your collection property with an empty list:

```
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public IList<ItemClass> Items { get; } = new List<ItemClass>();
```

However, the code analysis rule [explicitly says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2227#when-to-suppress-warnings):

> You can suppress the warning if the property is part of a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class.

Since you're deserializing this class from JSON, I think it's safe to assume it's a DTO. I would recommend using a pattern in your .globalconfig or .editorconfig files to suppress this rule for all of your DTO model classes.